# mysql insert into two tables id from first

Tags: php, mysql, bulkinsert

i need to insert some data into the table 'companies' with columns :
company_id | company_name

and at the same time (from the same form) into another table 'contact_persons' :
contact_name | company_id

where the company_id must be the value from 'companies' table where company_id is a PK and AI.
Is it possible to do that in ONE single step instead of inserting first the company_name and then reading the table 'companies' and retrieving the 'company_id' to insert it into the second table ('contact_persons')?

I'm not sure if that is possible, but it would be much more elegant and efficient...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can .please read this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last auto increment id from `Companies` table and inserting the same in other table. something like

```
INSERT INTO companies (company_name) VALUES ('test'); 
SET @last_id_companies = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO contact_persons (contact_name, company_id) 
                        VALUES ('test', @last_id_companies);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in a single statement, but in a single transaction, so they are both executed at the same time and rolled back.

```
START TRANSACTION;
--Your statements here
COMMIT;
```